# How to retrieve a node from a soap response?

Tags: xml, soap, soapui

I am new to SoapUI and SoapUI Pro. I came across a property transfer problem recently, of which I tried with no luck in googling for the solution.

I was practising with "country codes" from webservicex.net, and when I run the ""GetCountry" test request I will get a list of countries as the response.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetCountriesResponse xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
         <GetCountriesResult><![CDATA[<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <Name>Afghanistan, Islamic State of</Name>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Name>Albania</Name>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Name>Algeria</Name>
  </Table>
  .....
</NewDataSet>]]></GetCountriesResult>
      </GetCountriesResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

That is all good until the point that I want to retrieve only one of the countries from the data set, Algeria for instance. It's because I want to transfer the country name to the next test step which is a service taking a country name as a request. I tried to select the node from the response, however I noticed that the XPath I got was pointing to whole response instead of one of those nodes

```
declare namespace ns1='http://www.webserviceX.NET';
//ns1:GetCountriesResponse[1]/ns1:GetCountriesResult[1]
```

I guess it is probably very simple question to some of you here, but my XPath skills is kind of limiting my ability to solve it myself.   Much appreciated if anyone could help.

Answer (score 0):

Following XPath expression getting full response is exacted.

```
declare namespace ns1='http://www.webserviceX.NET';
//ns1:GetCountriesResponse[1]/ns1:GetCountriesResult[1]
```

Because its GetCountriesResult holds CDATA value and it's not parsed by the XML parser. So you need to get the result and put it in temporary stream and then parse and get the value.

Comment: Hi neo, do you have any suggestion on how to retrieve the nodes from the CDATA then?

Answer (score 0):

put your namespace name here

```
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
            $sxe->registerXPathNamespace('d', 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1');
            $result = $sxe->xpath("//NewDataSet");
            echo "<pre>";
            //print_r($result[0]);
            foreach ($result[0] as $title) {
                print_r($title);
                //echo $title->CityID;
        }
```